# How to end the execution of an action via an event

Tags: zend-framework2

in my ZF2 application I am adding the following event listener, however I want to make the execution of the action actually stop, however this doesnt happen.

```
 public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        parent::setEventManager($events);

        $controller = $this;
        $events->attach('dispatch', function ($e) use ($controller) {
            $request = $e->getRequest();
            $method = $request->getMethod();
            $headers = $request->getHeaders();

            // If we get here, based on some conditions, the original intended action must return a new JsonViewModel()...
            return new JsonViewModel([]); // However, this doesn't do anything.
        }, 100); // execute before executing action logic
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to return an empty view model, no matter what the action does? Or do you need to have the result of the action processed into a view model?

Comment: Well, ideally, I wanted to return a view with some data.. possibly new JsonViewModel(['someData'=>123]); ...  basically I am intercepting all the API calls, checking for a header and then either allowing the execution or returning some sort of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in your event:

```
$e->stopPropagation();
```

Comment: I basically want to do the same thing as @smorhaim but when I use $e->stopPropagation() before setting my new JsonModel() it just returns a regular text/html header,@smorhaim can you post your working code?

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comments, I am assuming you are doing some sort of authentication. You can perfecty use the event manager for this. However, I would not tie the listener to a single controller. If your API increases, you might want to split the API over several controllers and you get into trouble with your authentication.

My solution is to create a listener which listens to the dispatch event of the Zend\Mvc\Application. This is an event which is triggered before the event in the controllers itself.

```php
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $em  = $app->getEventManager();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager()->getSharedManager();

    $listener   = new Listener\Authentication();
    $identifier = 'MyModule\Controller\ApiController';

    $em->attach($identifier, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, $listener, 1000);
}
```

This way, the listener is attached to all controllers which are identified with `MyModule\Controller\ApiController`. The listener will be triggered on every dispatch call of those controllers. Your listener can short-circuit the complete dispatch loop in case you need it:

```php
use Zend\Http\Request as HttpRequest;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Json\Json;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class Authentication
{
    public function __invoke(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $request = $e->getRequest();

        if (!$request instanceof HttpRequest) {
            // Don't run on CLI requests
            return;
        }

        if ($result->isValid()) {
            // Say you get auth result and all is OK
            return;
        }

        // Case 1: short-circuit and return response, this is the fast way

        // The response I use here is the HTTP problem API
        $message  = array(
            'httpStatus' => 401,
            'title'      => 'Unauthorized',
            'detail'     => 'You are unauthorized to perform this request',
        );
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(401);
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->setContent(Json::encode($message);
        return $response;

        // Case 2: don't short circuit and stop propagation, you're using the JSON renderer

        $e->getResponse()->setStatusCode(401);
        $message  = array(
            'httpStatus' => 401,
            'title'      => 'Unauthorized',
            'detail'     => 'You are unauthorized to perform this request',
        );
        $model = new JsonModel($message);
        return $model;
    }
}
```

I would advice you to use the first method (returning the response yourself) because you'll short circuit the complete dispatch process and skip the complete finishing of the request. If you really rely on the view and response senders, use the second case.

Now if you need a controller which is authenticated via this system, add the identifier to this controller:

```php
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class MyFooBarApiController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $eventIdentifer = 'MyModule\Controller\ApiController';

    // your code here
}
```

If you need to allow certain requests without validation (I would always use a whitelist!), you can do this in your listener:

```php
use Zend\Mvc\Route\RouteMatch;

$routematch = $e->getRouteMatch();
if (!$routematch instance of RouteMatch) {
    // It's a 404, don't perform auth
    return;
}
$route = $routematch->getMatchedRouteName();

if (
    ($request->isPost() && 'foo/bar' === $route) 
 || ($request->isGet() &&  'baz/bat' === $route)
) {
    // We allow these requests to pass on without auth
    return;
}
```

In your code you can explicitly check request method and route name. If you need parameters of the route, you can access it with `$routematch->getParam('id')`.

Comment: juian: Your answer is correct. I do have one question....   The specific situation I need this for, is for AbstractRestfulController and so with the use of listeners I was able to pass the authentication .... however, I do need certain methods, to not require authentication. For this, I need to get the Action name in the listener....  the problem with this.... IS THAT.. the method is not defined until after the dispatch. The method name is determined with the POST/GET/PUT switch/case in the controller... so.. how would you get the Action name?

Comment: If you set  Authentication on MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH there is security concern because the logic from controller is still execute... right event to interrupt is MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE